# replace last character with first character for each line in textbox using multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have 3 textbox and two button,the first textbox is to specifies (n) number of lines and character in each line,the first button will randomly generate (n) number of lines inside the second textbox,the second button will read the lines from the second textbox and then replace the last character of each line with the first character.my question is that i need to know how to do this process with using multithread(depending on the Environment.ProcessorCount)
this is my code so far:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    static int processorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    Thread[] arrThr = new Thread[processorCount];
    static char[][] array;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size = Convert.ToUInt16(textBox1.Text);
        textBox2.Text = null;
        textBox3.Text = null;

        Random random = new Random(Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.Second));
        array = new char[size][];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new char[size];
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = (char)random.Next(33, 122);
                textBox2.Text += Convert.ToString(array[i][j]);
            }
            textBox2.Text += "\r\n";
        }        
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>(textBox2.Lines);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(lines[i].ToCharArray().Last(), lines[i].ToCharArray().First());
        }
        textBox3.Lines = lines.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the `Replace` method replaces *all* instances of a character in a string with another (not just the last one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, I think the code you posted doesn't work as expected, because the `Replace` method will replace *all* instances of one character with another one (not just the last one), so if there are other characters that match the last one in the string, then they will also be replaced.

To fix this, the code could be written something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count - 1; i++)
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Substring(0, lines[i].Length - 1) + lines[i].First();
}
```

To run this code in parallel, the .NET framework has the [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_For_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Action_System_Int32__) loop which can be leveraged:

```
Parallel.For(0, lines.Count - 1, i =>
{
    lines[i] = lines[i].Substring(0, lines[i].Length - 1) + lines[i].First();
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for the correcting,and about using thread i meant something more like what i wrote in the code (Thread[] arrThr),so i can divide the work of the program into sections that equals the number of the device processors(processorCount) and at the end gather all the results in some type of list or array and displays it in the third textbox

Comment: That's what `Parallel.For` does...it uses a thread pool managed by .NET. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff963552(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) *"For parallel loops, the degree of parallelism doesn't need to be specified by your code. Instead, the run-time environment executes the steps of the loop at the same time on as many cores as it can."*